# Foundation 6.2 Large Gutter Size

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

According to Foundation 6.2 documentation default grid gutter size for small    is 20px and for medium is 30px, but did not mention for large. What is the default gutter size for large?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [_grid.scss](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/master/scss/grid/_grid.scss) on the Foundation GitHub page:

> ```
> /// The amount of space between columns at different screen sizes. To use just one size, set the variable to a number instead of a map.
> /// @type Map | Length
> /// @since 6.1.0
> $grid-column-gutter: (
>   small: 20px,
>   medium: 30px,
> ) !default;
> ```

and [_column.scss](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/master/scss/grid/_column.scss):

> ```
> // Gutters
>   @if type-of($gutter) == 'map' {
>     @each $breakpoint, $value in $gutter {
>       $padding: rem-calc($value) / 2;
>
>       @include breakpoint($breakpoint) {
>         padding-left: $padding;
>         padding-right: $padding;
>       }
>     }
>   }
> ```

**There is no large gutter defined as the docs say.** So in this case **large gutters would be the same as medium** since Foundation uses mobile first.

You could add a custom large gutter by doing something like this:

```
$grid-column-gutter: (
  small: 20px,
  medium: 30px,
  large: 50px
) !default;
```

Comment: I changed the $grid-column-gutter settings but seems no effect?

Comment: @TwitterBootstrap I just tested it locally and it seems to work for me. Have you run `gulp build` to recompile the sass into css? Or maybe a more exaggerated value (e.g. 200px for large really stands out haha)

Comment: I'm running Foundation watch and made medium 90px.

Comment: Hmm, is it giving any errors? I just changed it in place in the _grid.scss file, are you changing it somewhere else?

Comment: You shouldn't overwrite the source Foundation files, FYI. There's a reason it has the `!default` flag. You should redefine the variable with your new data.